# Find Nearby GPS Navigation Route

Tags: c#, sql-server, navigation

I am developing a car pooling website. For that, I have created the database which has the different route options selected by different user. These routes are saved in the Database as Geography datatype. For data access, I used Entity Framework. In the C# code, I used DBGeography datatype for process the routes.

I have a requirement that, the user can select one route, and identify the users who selected the same/nearby route which is saved in the database. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: CONTAINS and NEAR would be a good starting point CONTAINS('NEAR((A, B), 5) AND/OR NEAR((C, D), 3)') http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlfts/archive/2011/11/15/custom-proximity-search-with-near-in-sql-server-2012.aspx